# How use state in component reactjs by react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an react component and inside it I have state called "user" with some data, I need this state in other component . please how do this with redux ?

Answer (score 1):

If `user` is part of the component's local state, and the other component is not nested inside it, then you need to move that piece of information out of local state and into Redux's store state.

Comment: If the other component is nested inside the component with `user` in local state, then you can pass it down as a prop.

Comment: It is not nested inside, I must use redux but I don't know how , please can you explain with an sample example ?

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation available at https://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/

Comment: Yes I did this but I don't arrive to do any small example .